# Tidyverse - rsample. nested_cv + group_vfold_cv = error. Nested cross-validation on caret (trainControl)

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am running on the following error:

```
library(tidymodels)
nested_cv(data = iris, outside = group_vfold_cv( data = iris, group = Species, v = 2), inside = bootstraps(times = 5)) %>% rsample2caret()
```

> Error: `labels` not implemented for nested resampling

I am unsure it is on development or if there is a correct way (or a different way) to input on caret/trainControl .

Comment: Make sure you tag questions with the language you're using, or it's unlikely for people to see them

Comment: Hey @camille,
You are an expert on rsample, right? I've seen your posts on other topics. ;) 

I am trying to drop a column which I used to create group_vfold_cv (in the example that would be "Species"). 

```
results$splits<- results$splits %>%
 map_depth(1, "data") %>% 
lapply(function(x) x[!(names(x) %in% c("Species"))])
```
When I run that, I (obviously) loose the other information created by rsample. Do you know  a better way to that?

Cheers,

PS:My account on SO is not highly ranked and I sometime it prevents me to include certain tags/keywords (sort of odd, I reckon).